# Can't Connect to SQL*Plus using SID

Tags: sql, oracle

I executed the following query to find the SID of the database that I was connected to as system:

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------
orcl
```

I then try connecting to system with the following command:

```
C:\>sqlplus system/system@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Aug 8 23:53:02 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

What can I do to connect to the database as system while specifying the SID?

Comment: Do you have `orcl` connect descriptor in tnsnames.ora file on the client? You can't connect to the database server using just SID.

Comment: Well, how did you connect the first time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a SID, you say? *Expand* the connect string a little bit. Here's how:

I'll use TNSPING to find information I need:

```
M:\>tnsping orcl

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-KOL-2018 07:13:18

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\0_Oracle_library\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=db_kc11g) (PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SID=kc11g)))
OK (20 msec)
```

Now, connect:

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=db_kc11g)(port=1521))(connect_data=(sid=kc11g)))

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Kol 9 07:14:05 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Or, shorter:

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@db_kc11g:1521/kc11g

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Kol 9 07:16:59 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Comment: If `@orcl` isn't recognised as a TNS alias then tnsping won't recognise it either, surely?

Comment: Absolutely, @Alex. I wanted to show that my "ORCL" didn't come from *nowhere*, but that there's some database that actually responds to that name.

Comment: @Littlefoot how oracle knows kc11g at the end of "scott/tiger@db_kc11g:1521/kc11g" is sid and not Service-Name? Did I missed something in syntax that points to that? 10q

Comment: @Ewoks, documentation says that - indeed - Oracle expects **service name** at the end, not the SID. I've just checked my TNSNAMES.ORA file - it says that both service name and SID are equal, which confused me.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that. Unfortunatelly I have no Service-Name, but know that I can connect with specific SID using OracleSQLDeveloper. Now is the question how to build connection string for SqlPlus, as using known SID at the end is recognised by oracle as service-name and I get error saying "ORA-12514: TNS: listener does not currently know of serivice requested in connect". I don't have TNSNAMES.ORA files neither... :/
@Littlefoot any further tip would be very appreciated

Comment: Huh. Usually, SID = SERVICE_NAME (but doesn't have to be). If you don't have TNSNAMES.ORA, can you create one (and then use it)? Or, use this "long" form (which has SID at the end)? `sqlplus scott/tiger@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=db_kc11g)(port=1521))(connect_data=(sid=kc11g)))`

Comment: I managed to do it with a long form.. Spend few hours and resolved by adding quotes, guess space was messing things up. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad you made it work, @Ewoks. Just being curious - which part of the connect string had the space?

Comment: part that describes connection to the server, after @ (what would be the content of tnsnames.ora if you use that file)

Comment: for bash you also need to quote the long form because of the parenthesis

Comment: This is **MS Winsows**, @Johan, but - thank you for the comment, I hope it'll help future readers.